# Number of votes on the election

Tags: support, election

The  [Constituent Badge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/badges/86/constituent) was awarded 149 times and also according to the [Travel SE election page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/1) :

> 784 voters were eligible, 330 visited the site during the election,
>   231 visited the election page, and 149 voted

But according to the [OpaVote result page](http://www.opavote.org/results/1042122/0):

> There are 5 candidates competing for 3 seats. The number of voters is
>   150 and there were 150 valid votes.

Is this a bug? What is the real number of voters?

Answer (score 1):

Since no answer in three years, I will speculate that OpaVote is correct, there were indeed 150 votes cast and that the discrepancy arises from one of those users being removed after the election and before your checking of the Constituent Badge page.

I don't see the timing of the Travel SE election page announcement but since after the election results were determined there was probably at least a small time interval between the end of the election and the announcement of the results during which a user might have been removed.

Possibly comparison between the 149 users and the data mentioned:

> Download the election data and use OpenSTV for windows or mac to audit the results.

might throw further light on the reason for the difference but since only 1 vote from three years ago not something I am inclined to pursue.